# Invalid Document Stream when uploading thumbnail to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

I download a JPEG thumbnail.

```
curl -L 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/EF393A3B6CA330A3!112/thumbnails/0/small/content' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $AUTH" \
   > image
```

I then try to use that very same downloaded image as a custom thumbnail.

```
curl -v 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/EF393A3B6CA330A3!112/thumbnails/1/source/content' \
  -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' -H "Authorization: Bearer $AUTH" \
  -d @image
```

but it doesn't work.

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Via: 1.1 BY3302____PAP061 (wls-colorado)
< Content-Length: 71
< Content-Type: application/json
* Server Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< X-WLSPROXY: BY3302____PAP061
< X-MSNSERVER: DM2301____PAP093
< X-QosStats: {"ApiId":0,"ResultType":2,"SourcePropertyId":0,"TargetPropertyId":42}
< X-ThrowSite: 3683.1abb
< X-AsmVersion: UNKNOWN; 19.22.0.0
< P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
< Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2015 06:59:24 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.onedrive.com left intact
{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Invalid Document Stream"}}
```

What does OneDrive want me to do to upload the thumbnail?

I looked at the ["example"](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/thumbnails.htm), but it didn't shed much light.

Comment: Is `EF393A3B6CA330A3!112` a folder or a file?

Comment: If you upload to `/thumbnails/0/source/content` instead does it work? Having said that I wouldn't expect hitting `/thumbnails/1/source/content` to fail with that specific error